# Android 6.0: Where are the cookies of a native Android browser stored?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, browser, cookies

I have a phone with *Android 6.0*. I'm trying to download the cookies file of a native browser.

For *Android 4.4* version the valid path is:

```
/data/data/com.Android.browser/database/webviewCookiesChromium.dB
```

Where are the native Android browser's cookies stored in Android 6.0?

Comment: On **Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini**, running **CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6.0.1)**, with the standard browser **Browser** (**Gello**, based on **Chromium**), the cookies are to be found at `/data/data/org.cyanogenmod.gello.browser/app_swe_webview/Default/Cookies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Moto X Play , running 6.0.1, it is here

```
/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/cookies
```

Comment: That's chrome, not native Android?